# How to add watermark on existing pdf file

Tags: watermark, pdfsharp

I am trying to add watermark on pdf file using PdfSharp, I tried from this link

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Watermark-sample.ashx

but am not able to get how to get the existing pdf file page object and how to watermark on that page.

Help?

Comment: That page only shows code snippets, look at the samples directory in the source zip I assume you downloaded. from: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx 
The samples are included in the PDFsharp source code package. So there is no need to copy and paste the code from this site (for some samples we only show snippets here).

You want PDFSharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_32/PDFsharp/samples/Samples C#/Based on GDI+/Watermark/Program.cs

Comment: @thecarpy, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the samples are only snippets. You can download the source and with that you get a bunch of samples, including this watermark example.

The following comes from `PDFSharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_32/PDFsharp/samples/Samples C#/Based on GDI+/Watermark/Program.cs`

Quite simple, really ... I am only showing the code up to the for loop that goes over each page. You should have a look at the full file.

```
  [...]
  const string watermark = "PDFsharp";
  const int emSize = 150;

  // Get a fresh copy of the sample PDF file
  const string filename = "Portable Document Format.pdf";
  File.Copy(Path.Combine("../../../../../PDFs/", filename),
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

  // Create the font for drawing the watermark
  XFont font = new XFont("Times New Roman", emSize, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

  // Open an existing document for editing and loop through its pages
  PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filename);

  // Set version to PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5) because we use transparency.
  if (document.Version < 14)
    document.Version = 14;

  for (int idx = 0; idx < document.Pages.Count; idx++)
  {
    //if (idx == 1) break;
    PdfPage page = document.Pages[idx];
  [...]
```